# How to setup Varnish to work with Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, varnish

I have a Ubuntu 12.0 server running Varnish 4 on port 80 and the Apache 2.4 in 8080. 
I installed Tomcat 7 running on port 8181, which runs only one Liferay site.
I would like to configure Varnish to work with Tomcat also.
How do I set this up?
My current setup is this:

```
/etc/default/varnish

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m"


/etc/varnish/default.vcl

backend default {
   .host = "123.456.789.000";
   .port = "8080";
   .connect_timeout = 580s;
   .first_byte_timeout = 580s;
   .between_bytes_timeout = 580s;
}
```

If I point my browser to 123.456.789.000:8181 the Tomcat site works. I will set the registar with my DNS to respond to "www.mytomcatsite.com", but how can I avoid the ":8181" on the URL ?

With Apache everything works fine.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the varnish documentation:

We add a new backend.:

```
backend java {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8000";
}
```

Now we need tell Varnish where to send the difference URL. Lets look at vcl_recv.:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/java/") {
        set req.backend_hint = java;
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    }
}
```

If you want this routing to be done on the basis of virtual hosts you just need to inspect req.http.host:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "foo.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = foo;
    } elsif (req.http.host ~ "bar.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = bar;
    }
}
```

See:

- https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-backends.html#multiple-backends
- https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-backends.html#backends-and-virtual-hosts-in-varnish

Note: This is for Varnish 4. The VCL syntax will be slightly different for Varnish 3.